# Angular 2+Heroku , always redirect to https:// instead of using http://

Tags: angular, heroku

I have an application of Angular 2 hosted in Heroku, I would like to redirect all http requests to https, what would be the correct way to do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wish to redirect any URL to its https equivalent, implement this class as a service. The class checks for developer mode so that redirect will only happen when the app is deployed in prod.

```
import {Injectable, isDevMode} from '@angular/core';
import {CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class IsSecureGuard implements CanActivate {

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    if (!(isDevMode()) && (location.protocol !== 'https:')) {
      location.href = 'https:' + window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

}
```

This guard must be applied to every path. For example:

```
 {path: 'mypath', component: MyPathComponent, canActivate: [IsSecureGuard]}
```